# Postgres update Query for Array column

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

This is so simple query. I need to update Bookings tables', LinkedBookings column (int array data type) to it's own Id. Below query didn't work for me.

```
update public."Booking" b set "LinkedBookings" = {"Id"}
```

Above is giving below error,

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
```

I searching thorough the internet and postgres documentation and couldn't find any proper simple query. I can understand there is a way to do with writing a Pg Function. Rather than doing such a big thing, isn't there any simple query for that?

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using? And are you certain your query is running in PL/pgSQL-mode?

Comment: Hello Dai, Its auto generated from DBviewer software. Anyways. Thanks for the comment. I got the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `LinkedBookings` is an array column and assuming that you want to set it to an array containing only the `Id` of each row, the correct `SQL` should be >>

```
   UPDATE public."Booking" b 
    SET "LinkedBookings" = ARRAY[b."Id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the the doc you were looking for](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT).

The syntax you used is for literals - you got the error because you're missing the single quotes around the brackets, and the entire thing should be a `text` before it can become an `int[]` array. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/280D6OED)

```sql
update public."Booking" b set "LinkedBookings" = ('{'||"Id"::text||'}')::int[]
  returning *,pg_typeof("LinkedBookings");
```

| Id | LinkedBookings | pg_typeof |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {1} | integer[] |
| 2 | {2} | integer[] |
| 3 | {3} | integer[] |

The alternative syntax is wrapping the value in `ARRAY[]`, already pointed out. You can add the explicit cast to be sure:

```sql
update public."Booking" b set "LinkedBookings" = (ARRAY["Id"])::int[];
```

If you're just making `"Id"` available in an alternative form to save array-wrapping elsewhere, you can consider setting up `"LinkedBookings"` as a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) - that way you don't need to keep refreshing the table with periodic `update`.

```sql
alter table public."Booking" drop column if exists "LinkedBookings";
alter table public."Booking" add column "LinkedBookings" int[] 
   generated always as ((ARRAY["Id"])::int[]) stored;
--no update necessary
select *,pg_typeof("LinkedBookings") from public."Booking";
```

| Id | LinkedBookings | pg_typeof |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {1} | integer[] |
| 2 | {2} | integer[] |
| 3 | {3} | integer[] |

If you're running this update to pre-populate the column and you plan to modify it later, don't make it `generated` as those cannot be modified directly. They can only be re-generated by modifying the values they depend on.